# Google Drive OAuth connect issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asynchronous, google-drive-api

In my program I use the following line to launch a browser window to make the user login and authorize permissions:

```
        try
        {
            using (var stream = GenerateClientSecretsStream(this._client_id, this._client_secret))
            {

                GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
                StoredCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new SavedDataStore()).Result;
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error when connecting to Google Drive");
            return;
        }
```

This works fine if you stay in the browser and follow the procedure as intended, but after testing if you close that window and return to the program it is frozen waiting for input back from the browser. I tried looking into async/await stuff but am using VS 2010 so it looks like those options are not available to me.

I have looked up Async CTP for VS 2010 but it is not recommended for release builds apparently. What can I do to prevent my program from locking up in this situation?

Comment: i am also stuck in the same scenario....may be it would only work in VS 2012

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari I believe that is what I ended up doing to make this work

Answer (score 0):

When you access the Result property of an async method, you are basically executing it synchronously, as it is actually the same as using Wait();

What you should do is await your method, which will yield control back to the caller until the method finishes executing:

### Edit

Forgot to mention, in case your method runs synchronously or returns void, it should change to the following signature:

**async Task MyFooMethod**

```
    try
    {
        using (var stream = GenerateClientSecretsStream(this._client_id, this._client_secret))
        {

            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
            await StoredCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
        DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new SavedDataStore());
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error when connecting to Google Drive");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: await is not available to me since I am using VS 2010

Comment: Did you find an answer Bryan? Having the same problem myself